# Should table-layout:fixed allow me to specify cell sizes that add up to a greater width than my container?

Tags: html, css

I thought that part of the appeal of `table-layout:fixed` was that you could set your cell widths to be whatever you want and the browser would blindly accept them.

I have a situation where I have a containing div set to 900px width.

In it is a table, with 4 columns, each set to 300px width.

The div has a background colour and is set to overflow:visible.

The result should be that the third column's right hand edge lines up with the right hand edge of the div, and the fourth column bursts out of the div.

But instead all four columns show *inside* the div, at about 225px each.

What can I do to alleviate this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: What is it you are trying to do? This seems like an odd use of table layout. Why not just use divs and widths? Did you try setting the width of the able to 900px?

Comment: have you set a width on the table? if not then the table will take 100% width and then the cell widths will be divided into the available space - have a read of the manual: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout

Comment: I agree @Paulie_D - it was just much simpler to explain it like that than to write out the full use-case.

Comment: Thanks for the link @Pete, that makes sense.  Should be a doddle to implement too!

Answer (score 0):

This is expected because, for your example, you need to specify a width of the `table` for the overlow to be effective.

> Under the "fixed" layout method, the entire table can be rendered once the first table row has been downloaded and analyzed. This can speed up rendering time over the "automatic" layout method, but subsequent cell content might not fit in the column widths provided. Cells use the overflow property to determine whether to clip any overflowing content, **but only if the table has a known width**; otherwise, they won't overflow the cells.
>
> <sup>[**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout)</sup>

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

div {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 1em auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
}

table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 300px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Item 1</td>
      <td>Item 2</td>
      <td>Item 3</td>
      <td>Item 4</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

An in-flow block-level table (`display: table`) with fixed layout and auto width is subject to the constraints specified in [section 10.3.3 of the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#blockwidth) (although the spec actually [allows browsers to skip fixed layout altogether for tables with auto width](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/tables.html#fixed-table-layout)). That is, the same constraints that apply to in-flow block boxes with auto width — the table will only be as wide as its containing block and any borders, padding and margins allow.

The workaround is trivial: specify any arbitrary table width that is known to never exceed the total column width — if the total column width will always exceed the container width, specifying 100% width works too:

```css
div {
  width: 900px;
  background-color: #ff0;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

td {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>1 <td>2 <td>3 <td>4
  </table>
</div>
```